# Representations of modular lattices, extension to cellular sheaves

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, lattice-theory, computational-topology

There are various "representation theorems" for lattices such as Birkhoff's Representation Theorem that states that *every finite distributive lattice is isomorphic to a quasi-sublattice of the lattice of subsets of some set*. There is an analogous Stone Representation Theorem for Boolean algebras.

Here is a fact that inspires this question: given a vector space $V$, the Grassmanian, $\mathrm{Gr}(V)$, is the lattice of subspaces of $V$ where joins are given by subspace sum, and meets by intersection.
Fact: $\mathrm{Gr}(V)$ is a modular lattice (this holds more generally for the lattice of subgroups of an abelian group, for example).

Here is my first question: *given a modular lattice, $L$, does there exist a vector space $V$ such that $L$ is isomorpic to a quasi-sublattice of $\mathrm{Gr}(V)$*? [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230527/representation-theorem-for-modular-lattices) may be a partial answer to this question, but perhaps there is more progress towards an answer in less generality.

Comment: What is the definition of quasi-sublattice?

Comment: @RichardStanley a quasi-sublattice is a subset closed under meets and joins but not necessarily empty meets and joins (i.e the top and bottom element of the lattice)

Answer (score 4):

The first question needs some kind of drastic modification to have a
chance of being true. For instance, let $L$ (respectively, $M$) be the
lattice of subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space over
$\mathbb{F}_2$ (respectively, $\mathbb{F}_3$), where $n\geq 3$. Then
the ordinal sum of $L$ and $M$ (just "stack" $M$ on top of $L$) is not
a quasi-sublattice of any $\mathrm{Gr}(V)$.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are aware of this, but there is a representation theorem for *atomic* modular lattices. Below I captured a picture of Theorem 7.56 on pg. 288 of Peter Cameron's "Introduction to Algebra":

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing this result. do you recall the definitions of a proper line or a proper projective plane?

Comment: addendum: in particular, since every finite lattice is trivially atomic, every finite modular lattice is classified as such... I also wonder if there is any particular structure to the direct product decomposition?

Comment: @Hans: line/projective plane have their usual meaning (a line is lattice which has a maximal element, a minimal element, and some number of atoms; a projective plane is a rank 3 lattice following the usual rules of lines=coatoms/points=atoms). But it is far from true that every finite lattice is atomic: here atomic means generated by atoms (this is also sometimes called 'atomistic,' I guess). E.g., the 5 element "pentagon" lattice is not atomic.

Comment: Unfortunately "atomic" has two meanings in lattices. For some (e.g. Stanley in Enumerative Combinatorics) "atomic" means every element is a join of atoms. For some (e.g. Grätzer in Lattice Theory: Foundation) "atomic" means every element majorizes an atom (trivially true in all finite lattices), and the previous thing is "atomistic".

Comment: @JukkaKohonen: that's true. Does it affect the answer, though?

Comment: The answer is fine, just noting that Cameron's "atomic" is the same as Stanley's.