Is there a proof of Wedderburn's and Artin–Zorn's theorems on finite division algebras using only synthetic projective geometry?
In this post, I don't require division algebras to be necessarily associative (but I do require a unit element). In synthetic projective geometry (part of incidence geometry), there is the notion of a projective plane: this is a set of lines and a set of points and a relation between them that captures the notion of incidence, i.e. when a point lies on a line, satisfying certain axioms.
One can associate to each alternative division algebra $D$ a projective plane $\Bbb P^2(D)$ that satisfies those axioms using the well-known ("analytic") construction by linear algebra: take a three-dimensional vector space $V$ over $D$ and define point in $\Bbb P^2(D)$ to be a 1-d subspace of $V$ and a line to be a 2-d subspace of $V$.
It turns out that there are some theorems from classical projective geometry (say over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) that don't hold in every projective plane, but the projective planes in which they hold can be described algebraically.
Namely,

A projective plane is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^2(K)$ for a (commutative) field $K$ if and only if Pappus's theorem holds.
A projective plane is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^2(D)$ for an associative division algebra $D$ if and only if Desargues's theorem holds.
A projective plane is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^2(A)$ for an alternative division algebra $A$ if and only if "little Desargues's theorem" hold.

Thus we have the following implications:
Pappus's theorem $\Rightarrow$ Desargues's theorem $\Rightarrow$ Little Desargues's theorem.
Which, in the light of the preceding list, are equivalent to the implications
field $\Rightarrow$ associative division algebra $\Rightarrow$ alternative division algebra.
The fact that Desargues's theorem implies Little Desargues's theorem is clear, but geometrically, it's not obvious that Pappus's theorem implies Desargues's theorem, although it is true by definition that a field is an associative division algebra. Still, a geometric proof was found by Gerhard Hessenberg.
But what is more striking is that if we assume that our division algebra (or equivalently, the associated projective plane) is finite, then all these implications may be reversed. Algebraically, this is the content of the theorems of Wedderburn and Artin–Zorn. Of course, this also implies the corresponding geometric statements for finite projective planes, but I have not found a geometric proof for these in the literature. A geometric proof that for finite projective planes, Little Desargues's theorem implies Desargues's theorem implies Pappups's theorem would yield a geometric proof of Wedderburn and Artin–Zorn, which I would find intriguing.

It's a result of Garrett Birkhoff that finite projective geometries (in any dimension) correspond to finite complemented modular lattices. The adjective modular can be replaced with a number of other ones, including atomic, etc. I'm not sure if this leads to a proof of what you are interested in, or if an approach based on lattice theory would qualify as geometric, but thought it worth mentioning in a comment.

(“The adjective modular…” should say “The adjective complemented…” in my previous comment. Modular is important. See also my previous MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431053 )

I'm reminded of a comment in (the now not-too-new) Artin's "Geometric Algebra" following the statement of the theorem that says "finite Desarguesian planes are Pappian". The comment says "no purely geometric proof is known for this theorem" referring to the fact that the Little Wedderburn theorem usually is demonstrated algebraically.  Are you essentially asking this question again? I've always wondered if such a proof appeared in the decades since the comment was written (1957).

At least for Wedderburn's theorem, this paper claims to do what you want:
Bamberg, John; Penttila, Tim, Completing Segre’s proof of Wedderburn’s little theorem, Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 47, No. 3, 483-492 (2015). ZBL1316.12001.
